# Create Silver UITabbar like Apple Music App?

Tags: user-interface, uitabbar

So I really want to implement a silver tab bar like the Apple Music app. I'm unsure about how to do it, specifically the silver look and feel.

Any help is much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is only for ios5 or later If you want to add this to ios4 you have to create custom tab bar. But in io5 You add the image on tabbar.

Answer (score 0):

Pick the silver color you like, and then change its appearance:

```
UIColor *navigationBarColor = [UIColor silverColor]; // silverColor doesn't exist, so make your own UIColor instance
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:navigationBarColor];
```

Note that this only works in iOS 5+.

Comment: That's for the navigation bar, I need the tab bar... Thanks though!

Comment: Do you know how I could make the exact silver by -(void)drawRect ?

Comment: Sorry, misread. The same applies to UITabBar though. I'm not sure what the exact silver is, you'll have to try some colors and see what's the closest to it.

Answer (score 0):

for iOS 5 and 6;

take a look at this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6

Comment: I don't suggest you to 'duplicate' an existing app registered with Apple. They might reject your app regarding Trademark issues and/or leading users for confusion. Anyways, if you are determined, you might download ipa file of music app (eg. via iExplorer) and navigate through its content, along with all png files. Its a bit hacky and sort of stealing trademarked media, but it might give you a hint to create your own similar looking design ;)